# jquery append class for a DIV dynamically

Tags: css

How do i append 'class' for a div using jquery.
This is the actual div.

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper-nav">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="assets/Images/Accessories/Ties/Knitted/LudlowDotKnittedTie.jpg"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to append class 'active-nav' to 'swiper-slide' div

The result is in the following way:

```
<div class="swiper-slide active-nav"><img src="assets/Images/Accessories/Ties/Knitted/LudlowDotKnittedTie.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: on which event ? hover or click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.thisclick').click(function(){
  $('.swiper-slide').addClass('active-nav');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$(".swiper-slide").addClass ("active-nav");
```